# two threads acting on the same runnable

Tags: java, concurrency, race-condition

Given:

```
public class Thread1 {
int x = 0;

public class Runner implements Runnable {

    public  void run() {
        int current = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            current = x;
            System.out.print(current + " ");
            x = current + 2;
        }
    }
}

public void go() {
    Runnable r1 = new Runner();

    new Thread(r1).start();
    new Thread(r1).start();


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread1().go();
}

}
```

Which two are possible results? (Choose two)

A. 0, 2, 4, 4, 6, 8, 10, 6,

B. 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 2, 4,

C. 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14,

D. 0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8, 10, 10, 12, 12, 14, 14,

E. 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14,

I chose A and B but I'm not certain if that is the correct answer.

Comment: This example is inherently flawed in that x is a shared variable between the two threads, but does not have the "volatile" modifier.  Therefore, each thread is free to cache the value of x, rather than reading it every time it's accessed (which is what the volatile keyword forces).

Comment: even if the values are cached, B will not happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all D. and E. are out. As `i` scope local to the function, we know that there is going to be 8 numbers.

Now

`B. 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 2, 4,`

is incorrect. Why? In order print the last two positions each thread has to ***write*** the variable `x` at least two times. At this point the minimum value for `x` is `4`. Which means that whatever the race conditions, the last two values should be greater or equal to `4`.

***EDIT***
`C` is totally possible. Absence of synchronization doesn't mean it is not possible to have what is called a serial execution (ie as if threads execute one after another). The lesson from concurrency is that you don't know how threads will be interleaved

```
    C. 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14,
```

happens for example :

- when the first thread as time to finish updating `x` before the second start
- when the first thread is suspended before the first `current = x;`, the second finish executing and the first continue.
- ***tons*** of other cases.

As Brian Goetz said:

> *"Writing correct programs is hard; writing correct concurrent programs is harder."*

Comment: But answer C seems to be impossible to occur because run() isn't synchronized!!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is A and C. You can eliminate D and E immediately because both threads will display 4 results, so 8 results in total, leaving only A, B & C in play.

B is eliminated because the sequence between the two 2's is too long for a single thread to have produced, so both threads must have done more work than only reaching 2.

Comment: how is that different to what i wrote 10 mins earlier?

Comment: @UmNyobe didn't see your answer until after I posted.

Comment: @jonathan.cruz D & E have too many results. There can only be 8 results in total (4 from each thread). Also, each number may show up twice but it is possible (and highly likely) that they wont, because of the way each thread shares the variable x.

Comment: 0 0 2 2 4 4 6 6 is what i get when i run it. 8 results is correct, i focused on the order rather than the amount of loops.

Comment: jonathan the result you gave is just one possible result. if you run the program several times you will see that the ouput changes.